# How to insert an object from SVG file using javascript/html?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have an SVG file with a bunch of different objects on one layer. Is there anyway to display a specific object from the file on a webpage without first splitting the objects out into their own file?

Comment: That’s a perfect use case for the `use` element ... https://css-tricks.com/svg-use-with-external-reference-take-2/

Comment: @CBroe that's perfect thank you. Unfortunately I can't mark it as the right answer.

Comment: Added it as an answer for you, with a little more info on `use`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That’s a perfect use case for the `use` element ...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use:

> The `<use>` element takes nodes from within the SVG document, and duplicates them somewhere else. The effect is the same as if the nodes were deeply cloned into a non-exposed DOM, and then pasted where the use element is

---

https://css-tricks.com/svg-use-with-external-reference-take-2/ explains how to make use of it for an SVG icon system, where all the icons are combined into one single SVG. Might be adaptable for your use, or at least give some more insight on how this works.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Give an `ID` or a `class` to the object in the SVG code. Then you can hide the `objects` via

```
.mySvgObjectClass { 
    visibility: hidden
}
```

or in Javascript

```
document.querySelector('.mySvgObjectClass').style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

or in jQuery:

```
$('.mySvgObjectClass').css('visibility', 'hidden');
```

Comment: Thanks I think I've got it figured out now.